# Extract string using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm struggling a bit on how to extract (i.e. assign to variable) a string based on a regex. I have the regex worked out -- I tested on regexpal. But I'm lost on how I actually implement that in Python. My regex string is:

```
http://jenkins.mycompany.com/job/[^\s]+
```

What I want to do is take string and if there's a pattern in there that matches the regex, put that entire "pattern" into a variable. So for example, given the following string:

```
There is a problem with http://jenkins.mycompany.com/job/app/4567. We should fix this.
```

I want to extract `http://jenkins.mycompany.com/job/app/4567`and assign it a variable. I know I'm supposed to use re but I'm not sure if I want re.match or re.search and how to get what I want. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
p = re.compile('http://jenkins.mycompany.com/job/[^\s]+')
line = 'There is a problem with http://jenkins.mycompany.com/job/app/4567. We   should fix this.'
result = p.search(line)
print result.group(0)
```

Output:

```
http://jenkins.mycompany.com/job/app/4567.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the first found match in the string, using the `re.findall` method to select the first match:

```
re.findall(pattern_string, input_string)[0] # pick the first match that is found
```